# How to create a wordpress search form that searches only videos in the media library using tag, category, or title

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, search-form

I have a site that I am creating (using wordpress) that is basically a simple video portal.  It displays a grid of all the videos (post_mime_type = video/mp4) in the media library.  I also have 6 buttons that filter videos based on category (when clicked, the page displays only videos within that category, while hiding the rest, using jquery).

The client also wants to be able to search the videos (using title, tag, and/or category) with a search form.

For example:

If a user inputs "health" into the search form, I need to query the database (in wp_posts) for all media files (post_type = attachment) that are videos (post_mime_type = video/mp4) that contain the search term (in this case, "health") anywhere within the title of the video, any of the categories attached to the video, or any of the tags attached to the video.

I know the basics of querying the WPDB using mysql and using wp_query and that category and tag lives in taxonomy somewhere outside of the wp_posts, but my brain cannot wrap around how to put this all together in a sql query that works or a wp_query arg that works.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can write a complex code by using the awesome wp_query or install "Relevanssi – A Better Search — WordPress Plugin" and combine the plugin with your wp_query.

Below a simple example for how you can combine Relevanssi with wp_query:

```
     $wp_args = array(
     's'                => 'health',
     'posts_per_page'   => 10,
     );


     $wp_query = new WP_Query( $wp_args ); relevanssi_do_query( $wp_query );
     if( $wp_query->have_posts() ): while( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
```